# Slack API - How to get bot_id when bot has no conversation history?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to get the `bot_id` value for a bot when it has no conversation history.

According to the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/bots.info):

> the bot_id fields appear in bot_message message event subtypes and in
> the response of methods like conversations.history.

This makes sense and works.

But is it possible to get this `bot_id` value, when a bot has no conversation history?

For example, say the channel between Slackbot and my bot has no conversation history. The response of a `conversations.history` request to this channel is the following, which does not include the `bot_id` value.

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "channel": {
        "id": "DC6N8Q1BK",
        "created": 1534129098,
        "is_im": true,
        "is_org_shared": false,
        "user": "USLACKBOT",
        "last_read": "0000000000.000000",
        "latest": null,
        "unread_count": 0,
        "unread_count_display": 0,
        "is_open": true,
        "priority": 0
    }
}
```

Any other way to get the `bot_id` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a bot user, you can get it from the normal userlist with [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list). But that will not include other apps.

Then there is the unofficial API method [bots.list](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/bots.list.md). That will give you a list of all bots, but its not officially supported and you will need a legacy token to use as with many undocumented methods.

Comment: Thanks! I totally looked over the users.list result and didn't see it, but you're right it is there